# HTML image - mime-type

Tags: html, image, mime-types, data-uri

I was looking into MIME types and there is something I don't understand yet.

I want to display a Base64 image in my page body.

I know this example works:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dENbMY831wKz4Y/VHb/5RGQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ
 0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0PzMWtyaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoxtb0QGho
 aGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaMbRLEvv50VTQ9OTQ5OpyZ01GpM2g0bfmDQaL7S+ofFC6x
 v3ZpxJiywakzbvd9r3RWPS9I2+MWk0+kbf0Hih9Y17U0nTHibrDDQ0NDQ0NDQ0
 NDQ0NDQ0NTXbRSL/AK72o6GhoaGhoRlL8951vwsNDQ0NDQ1NDc0WyHtDTEhD
 Q0NDQ0NTS5MdGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGposzSHAAErMwwQ2HwRQ
 AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="beastie.png">
```

I am wondering, can I also achieve it with something like this?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/png;">
</head>
<body>
<img src="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD
 NCAMAAAAsYgRbAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c
 cllPAAAABJQTFRF3NSmzMewPxIG//ncJEJsldTou1jHgAAAARBJREFUeNrs2EEK
 gCAQBVDLuv+V20dENbMY831wKz4Y/VHb/5RGQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ
 0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0PzMWtyaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoxtb0QGho
 aGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaMbRLEvv50VTQ9OTQ5OpyZ01GpM2g0bfmDQaL7S+ofFC6x
 v3ZpxJiywakzbvd9r3RWPS9I2+MWk0+kbf0Hih9Y17U0nTHibrDDQ0NDQ0NDQ0
 NDQ0NDQ0NTXbRSL/AK72o6GhoaGhoRlL8951vwsNDQ0NDQ1NDc0WyHtDTEhD
 Q0NDQ0NTS5MdGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGhoaGposzSHAAErMwwQ2HwRQ
 AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="beastie.png"> </body>
```

Comment: What don't you get? Perhaps less clear to you than your readers is the fact you've not asked a question. An explicit question is far better than an implied one. ;)

Comment: do you mean it does work? my question was, does it work like i showed in the second example. i mean with a similar syntax

Comment: Ahh - I misread the sentence (that's missing a ? -I'll edit it in) between the 2 code snippets, sorry about that. Nope - that doesn't work. (0) the mime-type of the html document can't legally be `image/png` and (1) the dataURL string needs to include the mime-type. So, the syntax of the 2nd one isn't close and you nearly nailed it - it's just wrong, unfortunately. Basically put, in my understanding any dataURL can be copied and pasted into a browser's address bar. The base64 string in your first example satisfies this criteria, the 2nd does not.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/png;">` describes (poorly) the content-type for the **HTML document**.

`src="iVBORw0KG etc etc` is a **relative** URL that will be fetched over whatever scheme (usually HTTP) was used to fetch the HTML document.

If you want to switch schemes (which you need to do for a `data:` URI) then you need an absolute URI.

(That simplifies slightly. Scheme relative URIs do exist, but don't help with your problem.)

Comment: thank you very much! But what is the actual use for the content-type tag in the head then?

Comment: for example when will "image/png" be used?

Comment: @Herrsocke — As a terrible, terrible way to specify the character encoding using parameters. `image/png` there would just be an error.